# li:hover - is it possible to change language of text?

Tags: jquery, css

A bit of a weird one,

I know some of you might ask why, but I was wondering if you could change the language of some links once the user hovers over them?

```
nav li:hover {
   **change language here**
}
```

I was actually looking to convert English to Japanese, I'm assuming this isn't done with CSS, anyone have any ideas on how I'd go about this?

thanks

Comment: You can store Japanese and English text in separate span's and toggle them on hover.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it with javascript, but a CSS only implementation could be like so:

```
<ul class="languages">
    <li>
        <p class="english">English text here</p>
        <p class="japanese">Japanese text here</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

with CSS:

```
.languages li .japanese { display: none; }
.languages li:hover .english { display: none; }
.languages li:hover .japanese { display: block; }
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/GtHFS/) is a jsFiddle example.

Answer (score 2):

I see two ways to do that in CSS - no javascript or even jQuery is needed:

### Use an attribute and the `content` CSS property

```
<li data-japanese="こんにちは世界">hello world</li>
```

```css
li:hover {
    content: attr(data-japanese);
}
```

### Use two elements that are shown alternately

```
<li><span lang="ja">こんにちは世界</span><span lang="en">hello world</span></li>
```

```css
li [lang=ja], li:hover span {
    display:none;
}
li:hover [lang=ja] {
    display:inline;
}
```

This approach is has greater flexibility and is also semantically more sound.

([example at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/EZqTK/))

Comment: Using the current version of Chrome (28), your first example in your jsFiddle is not working.  Also, I advise against putting the Japanese value in the tag attributes for SEO purposes.

Comment: Ah, seems to be working in Opera only. And I already said that it's not very semantic, yeah :-)